# Getting values from a list of length-2 lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

There is a defconstant statement:

```lisp
(defconstant *contant2* '((Allan 4) (Zols 5) (Milo 2) (Judh 0)))
```

I want to take separated from this constant the name and the value associated with the name. How can I do that?

I need to achieve this goal:

> Give taste scores: `((name-1 score-1) ... (name-n score-n))` as an argument, LISP functions which avare score and other which generate word scores (9-10 is VeryGood, 7-8 is Good).

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Have you even tried to solve This? please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your direct question:

```
? (mapcar #'car *cookie-scores*)
(JOHN MARY MIKE JANE)
? (mapcar #'cadr *cookie-scores*)
(8 9 1 0)
```

In a `loop`, you can use `loop`'s destructuring:

```
for (name val) in
```

Other options are available; here's 2 example implementations of the required functions that I will leave uncommented; *please* ask questions, or show us your code.

```
(defun average-score (lst)
  (/ (reduce #'+ lst :key #'cadr) (length lst))))

? (average-score *cookie-scores*)
9/2
```

and

```
(defun word-scores (lst)
  (loop 
    for (name val) in lst
    collect (list name
                  (cond
                   ((> val 8) 'Excellent)
                   ((> val 6) 'Tasty)
                   ((> val 0) 'Terrible)
                   (t         'Garbage)))))

? (word-scores *cookie-scores*)
((JOHN TASTY) (MARY EXCELLENT) (MIKE TERRIBLE) (JANE GARBAGE))
```

Comment: In this context, it is clearer to use the names `first` and `second` instead of the functionally equivalent `car` and `cadr`.